# What is the NewableFunction interface used for?

Tags: typescript

A lesser known built-in interface in TypeScript is `VoidFunction`, which supposedly represents any function that takes no parameters and returns void. An even lesser known one is `NewableFunction`, which *sounds like* it should represent any function that is "newable" or "constructable" (probably with a construct signature like (`new (...) => ...`), but when you try to use this interface, you get unexpected behavior.

Try taking the parameters, for example. With `Parameters<VoidFunction>`, you get the expected `[]`:

```
// Makes sense
type VoidParams1 = Parameters<VoidFunction>;
//   ^? []
```

and using `ConstructorParameters` gives you an error, since `VoidFunction` is not constructable. However, *both* `Parameters` and `ConstructorParameters` don't accept `NewableFunction`:

```
//@ts-expect-error Is newable, not a regular function
type CtorParams1 = Parameters<NewableFunction>;
// What?
type CtorParams2 = ConstructorParameters<NewableFunction>;
// Error:                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Type 'NewableFunction' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.
```

which is already odd enough, but then when you use it as a type in code:

```
function newfn(f: NewableFunction) {}

// This line is OK
newfn(class {});
// Error on the following line
newfn(Date); // `new Date()`...?
//    ^^^^
// Argument of type 'DateConstructor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NewableFunction'.
//   Types of property 'apply' are incompatible.
//     ...
//       Type 'new () => any' is not assignable to type '(this: any) => any'.
```

What's the point of `NewableFunction` then, if I can't use it as a *newable function*? And why isn't a type like `new (...args) => any` built-in already? It's quite common to see/use. Issue [ms/TS#44337](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44337) doesn't seem to address these concerns...

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoARPN)

---

It seems that it accepts only "strictly newable" functions - functions that can only be invoked with `new`? Using `newfn(Date)` throws an error, but `newfn(Float32Array)` doesn't. But again, why is it designed like this? Why is this useful?

Comment: Isn't that unhappy with `Date` because, although it _is_ newable, it's also _directly callable_? `class NewableDate extends Date {}`, which inherits the "class part" but not the "function part", works fine in `newfn`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Great observation. I tested it with `Float32Array` (which can only be constructed with `new` and it seems about right). But then, **why** is that the case? Why does it only accept strictly newable functions? Surely the consumer of the value shouldn't care if it can also be called as a regular function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, I don't know how I missed this, but in the [release notes of version 3.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html), we got `strictBindCallApply`, which was implemented in part by two new interfaces, `CallableFunction` and `NewableFunction`. `VoidFunction` doesn't have anything to do with this.

```
function foo(a: number, b: string): string {
  return a + b;
}
let a = foo.apply(undefined, [10]); // error: too few argumnts
let b = foo.apply(undefined, [10, 20]); // error: 2nd argument is a number
let c = foo.apply(undefined, [10, "hello", 30]); // error: too many arguments
let d = foo.apply(undefined, [10, "hello"]); // okay! returns a string
```

Here's what they had to say about these new interfaces:

> This is achieved by introducing two new types, `CallableFunction` and `NewableFunction`, in `lib.d.ts`. These types contain specialized generic method declarations for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` for regular functions and constructor functions, respectively. The declarations use generic rest parameters (see [#24897](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24897)) to capture and reflect parameter lists in a strongly typed manner. In `strictBindCallApply` mode these declarations are used in place of the (very permissive) declarations provided by type Function.

So they're not really meant to be used by us, the regular users of TypeScript...